# Django form imagefield appear in self.data but none in self.cleaned_data

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a modelForm and imagefield in model. 
Everything seems ok in form.

I put a debugger in save method of form.

self.data appears like below

`<QueryDict: {u'city': [u'19105'], u'surname': [u'VARGI'], u'name': [u'Tuna'], u'image': [u'996884_10151559653258613_1077262085_n.jpg'], u'user': [u'1'], u'interest': [u''], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'pHAfb5EJBc7N3Xa8YxTQKRrSDeLdBugh'], u'biography': [u'asdasdasdasdasda']}>`

and self.is_valid() is True and self.errors is empty

but my self.clean() is

`{'city': <City: Ankara, Ankara, Turkey>, 'is_featured': False, 'biography': u'asdasdasdasdasda', 'surname': u'VARGI', 'name': u'Tuna', 'image': None, 'is_active': False, 'user': <Member: tuna>, 'interest': [], 'email': u'', 'categories': []}`

image come as None. Any ideas ?

By the way, i can add an image from django-admin

Comment: You have probably forgotten to bind the image data to the form: [Read this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files)

Comment: The relevant docs can now be found here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/fields/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure you have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` set on your html tag. And make sure you pass `request.FILES` into the form. For example: `form = MyAwesomeForm(request.POST, request.FILES)`